# Unity is not responding in Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: unity

I am running the build Unity executable in ubuntu 18.04 and it may take a while to load the asset. When I wait, I always receive a window telling me "You can choose to wait for a while to let it continue or force the application to completely exit." For a while, Unity will run and it looks like works well.
My question is, what is the impact of this? Why does ubuntu send the message? How to deal with it?
[image]

Comment: Unity in linux? run away from that.

Comment: I need to run in linux, could you pls give some advice anyway

Comment: linux does not give good support for graphic works. im not a linux user and never iisntalled unity on linux. hope another one can help you

Comment: This looks like a question [the Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) might be better-able to help you with, since it's about the behaviour of the OS and not about how to develop a game. If you choose to ask there, please remember to delete the version of the question here first, as cross-posting is discouraged between StackExchange sites.

Comment: @virtouso I think your comment is misleading. There are plenty of programs that do graphical work, and there is no problem with them. Unity's linux version is simply unstable, and last time I checked it was still on alpha.

Comment: @TomTsagk but in the end linux is not best place for graphics and simulations.

Comment: @virtouso linux has options for people wanting to work with either graphics or simulations. Wether people prefer it or not is another topic. I've used the Godot engine on linux and it runs extremely well on my low-end computer. Unity crashing on linux is not a linux problem, but a Unity one.